# Simplest React-native setTimeout not waiting

Tags: react-native, settimeout

I need to delay the execution of a fetch function but I cannot even make a simple setTimeout work!

```
 const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));


    while (true) {
      await delay(10000)
      console.log(new Date())  
    }
```

console.log's

```
 LOG  2021-05-04T08:36:18.833Z
 LOG  2021-05-04T08:36:21.598Z
 LOG  2021-05-04T08:36:21.615Z
 LOG  2021-05-04T08:36:21.618Z
 LOG  2021-05-04T08:36:22.665Z
 LOG  2021-05-04T08:36:22.667Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why setTimeout, setInterval and timers in general did not work, was because I mounted my Component several times from App.js. This happened because I used asynchronous useState, not realizing that it re-rendered all my components and somehow messing with the timers.

I could also be because I was in debug mode and there was an offset between the debugger and the app

Answer (score 1):

what about this:

```
let fetchTimer;

const delayedFetch = () => {
    clearTimeout(fetchTimer);

    fetchTimer = setTimeout(() => {                   
        doFetch();
        clearTimeout(fetchTimer);
    }, 10000);
}
```